# Trying to get google sheets data onto my flask web app (where does my .json file go?)

Tags: python, json, web, flask, google-api

I'm trying to setup a webapp that will get data from google sheets and display it. I got the idea from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vISRn5qFrkM&t=330s) video by twilio and even got it working locally. Now i'm trying to have it display info into an html doc but can't quite get it to work on my server. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with this...

```
json_data = open(os.path.join(static, "getinfo.json"), "r")
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_data, scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open('hotlistsouthforsyth').sheet1
```

am I just not putting my "getinfo.json" in the right place?

here is the entire code i'm working with...

this is my __init __.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, json
import random
import spreadsheet

app = Flask(__name__)

def function_test():
    r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
    return '#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r())

@app.route('/')

def homepage():
    firstName = spreadsheet.getInfo()
    textColor = function_test()
    return render_template("home.html", textColor=textColor)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

this is the spreadsheet.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, json
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

json_data = open(os.path.join(static, "getinfo.json"), "r")
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_data, scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open('hotlistsouthforsyth').sheet1

def getUniId(x):
     myvalue = sheet.cell(x,6).value
     return(str(myvalue))
def getFirstName(x):
     myvalue = sheet.cell(x,2).value
     return(str(myvalue))
def getLastName(x):
     myvalue = sheet.cell(x,3).value
     return(str(myvalue))
def getGender(x):
     myvalue = sheet.cell(x,4).value
     return(str(myvalue))
def getImg(x):
     myvalue = sheet.cell(x,5).value
     return(str(myvalue))
def getScore(x):
     myvalue = sheet.cell(x,6).value
     return(str(myvalue))
def getAll(x):
     getUniId(x)
     getFirstName(x)
     getLastName(x)
     getGender(x)
     getImg(x)
     getScore(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

SITE_ROOT = app.root_path

json_data = open(os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "static", "getinfo.json"), "r")

Whether this works or not, figure out where the debugger is in your IDE and set a breakpoint on that line, so that you can follow the object's state and identify where the breakdown is. Once you have that specific info, much easier to post it and get an answer on here.